# Can not move files to trash from ext4 partition

Tags: partitioning, ext4, trash

I have lubuntu 16.04 and windows vista installed in dual-boot.

I have just created a new ext4 partition which is working well with lubuntu except that the files I delete from there are not moved to trash but permanently deleted.

I have already tried to create a .Trash-1000 folder in this new ext4 partition but without any change.

Here is my fstab file (where I am not sure to see my new ext4 partition):

```
*UUID=a12e62f7-8eaa-4aba-8c59-7fbf4ce9148c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=90e31a06-2ba1-4119-b640-14f900268f84 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/07D8-0713 /mnt/07D8-0713 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/E49E631C9E62E690 /mnt/E49E631C9E62E690 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/66D25FBFD25F9263 /mnt/66D25FBFD25F9263 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0*
```

Could you please help?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to move files to trash from other `ext` partitions?

Comment: Yes I can move files to trash from the main partition where I have my \home\

Comment: That's not a valid fstab file. How did it get created... manually from scratch?

Comment: No I didn't edit this file. I just got it like that. Why is it not valid ?

Comment: What's the output of this command: `gvfs-trash filename` which `filename` is the file , that you can't move it to trash ?

Comment: There was no output to the command gvfs-trash and the file moved to the new folder /media/.../.Trash-1000/files. But if I try to delete the file with "delete" or "move to trash" it is deleted permanently (not moved to trash)

Comment: @Carlo What is the output of `locate Trash | xargs ls -ld`?

Comment: I get `drwxr-xr-x 34 carlo carlo 4096 june  15 20:58`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Made an account just to say this. My Ext4 has been created in Gparted on Ubuntu 15.04. On a same hard drive there is HFS+ partition that I use for Time Machine backup on my MacBook. Ext4 partition is working "normal" on both Ubuntu and MacOS its just that files never go to trash but are deleted directly. Its a new partition that I have created yesterday and its been behaving like that from a start. (Can not post commnets cause I dont have enough experience or something).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 - Therefore files is replaced by nautilus and gvfs-trash by gio.
I am having the same issue.
If you try to move a file to trach on a device other than the one containing your home directory then one in the home directory gio will attempt to move to a sub directory in the top level directory called Trach-*uid* I that direct does not exist then gio will attemt to create if. This will often fail due to protection issues.
The solution would be to create this folder by and and make sure its ownership is correct.