# not valid fstab

Tags: partitioning, fstab

I have lubuntu 16.04 and windows vista installed in dual-boot.

I have recently created a new ext4 partition and I had a concern with moving files to trash. I have heard from someone from this forum that my fstab file was not "valid". I really don't know what this means.

Here is my fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=a12e62f7-8eaa-4aba-8c59-7fbf4ce9148c /               ext4        errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=90e31a06-2ba1-4119-b640-14f900268f84 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/07D8-0713 /mnt/07D8-0713 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/E49E631C9E62E690 /mnt/E49E631C9E62E690 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/66D25FBFD25F9263 /mnt/66D25FBFD25F9263 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
```

I have absolutely no idea about what I may change on my stab file to make it "valid".

Could you please help me?

Comment: seems valid to me, if it works and you have access to all your partitions then it's valid ;)

Comment: Try running `sudo mount -a` and see if the OS complains. If it doesn't, then it's valid.

Comment: OK thank you. I tried `sudo mount -a` and nothing happened. Everything works fine except that I can not move files to trash, already posted here[https://askubuntu.com/questions/921877/can-not-move-files-to-trash-from-ext4-partition]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `sudo mount -a` and see if the OS complains. If it doesn't, then it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sudo mount -a` command to see if Ubuntu complains about any of your file system entries, but another method I found that I like even better is the findmnt command.

```
sudo findmnt --verify --verbose
```

What this does is analyzes each entry and advises you if there are any concerns about the lines in the /etc/fstab file. You will get feedback that says if the line passes its tests, you may get warnings suggesting that something could be done better (such as if your swap entry is a regular file instead of a partition or file system), or if any entries are totally wrong and would cause an issue during reboot phase.

The findmnt command won't fix anything for you. It's just reporting what it sees as a potential issue. It's up to the admin to then decide if there is something that needs to be fixed.